# CSS - Relative size(proportion) Of Any Size Image

Tags: html, image, css, size

I have a project thats envolve alot of images.

The problem is that is to each image has diffrent resolution (Height / Width). It's going from small images like 200x600 to 3000x5000 lol.

I'm trying to find a way to decrease the size to all images to (MAX-300X300) but still save the proportion of the images - so if it was a wide img it will stay wide BUT - in the bounds of max-300x300. I just can't find a way to do this correcty for NO MATTER what is the size images.

This is what I tried :

```
Max-Height:300px;
Max-Width:300px;
```

But still it doesn't work very well.... any suggestions?

Comment: you should try `max-width: 300px; ` without using `max-height` and add `overflow: hidden;` to the image container

Comment: There are no capiatl letters on the `max-width`/`max-height` attributes  your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the image inside a `<table><tr><td>` with a height and width specified, in this case, say 300px x 300px, and assign max-height: 100%; and max-width: 100% to `<img>`, and vertical align to `<td>`.

Here's a solution I've worked out for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fw3s/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @BlackPanther. I tried this either. But the problem is that im a trying to "Box" the images- so They all will be the same size in the browser- but will keep it relative. So if it's Wide it will stay wide but some how the "border" will stay inhale to the Max-Height and Max-Width so it will appear as a box.. Any idea?